# Saving javascript array into Postgres polygon field

Tags: javascript, postgresql, geometry, postgis, typeorm

I'm having trouble trying to save a polygon that I have formatted like GeoJSON and the problem is that I've got the polygon as an array of arrays of coordinates but postgres polygon field is expecting an array of tuples but javascript doesn't have support for tuples and thus I can't figure out how to insert the data into Postgres.

**Example of how postgres wants the data:**

`INSERT INTO table VALUES(default, '[(x,y), (x,y)]');`

**Example of the data i have:**

```
"coordinates": [
          [
            [
              49.5703125,
              59.5343180010956
            ],
            [
              54.84375,
              54.77534585936447
            ],
            [
              63.28125,
              59.5343180010956
            ],
            [
              54.84375,
              61.77312286453146
            ],
            [
              49.5703125,
              60.930432202923335
            ],
            [
              49.5703125,
              59.5343180010956
            ]
          ]
        ]
```

Error that I've got when trying to save the array to postgres:

```
{
    "message": "invalid input syntax for type polygon: \"{{\"-64.1892249612655\",\"-31.4212119274207\"},{\"-64.1896863245919\",\"-31.4223122073094\"},{\"-64.1900957427429\",\"-31.423283040535\"},{\"-64.1901970936061\",\"-31.4235231632172\"},{\"-64.190677427225\",\"-31.4246610035708\"},{\"-64.1892249612655\",\"-31.4212119274207\"}}\"",
    "name": "QueryFailedError",
    "length": 353,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "22P02",
    "file": "float.c",
    "line": "542",
    "routine": "float8in_internal",
    "query": "INSERT INTO \"zones\"(\"title\", \"boundary_points\", \"created_at\", \"updated_at\", \"iconFileId\", \"backgroundFileId\") VALUES ($1, $2, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $3, $4) RETURNING \"id\", \"created_at\", \"updated_at\"",
    "parameters": [
        "BAJO GENERAL PAZ",
        [
            [
                -64.1892249612655,
                -31.4212119274207
            ],
            [
                -64.1896863245919,
                -31.4223122073094
            ],
            [
                -64.1900957427429,
                -31.423283040535
            ],
            [
                -64.1901970936061,
                -31.4235231632172
            ],
            [
                -64.190677427225,
                -31.4246610035708
            ],
            [
                -64.1892249612655,
                -31.4212119274207
            ]
        ],
        null,
        null
    ]
}
```

Comment: every point of this array should become a record in your table?

Comment: No, It's only one record, there's a field that I've called 'boundary_points' which is of type Polygon, in order to define a polygon in postgres you need to pass an array of tuples (x,y) of coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your GeoJSON polygon is invalid - it is missing the type: `"type":"Polygon"`. If you want to store a GeoJSON polygon into a `GEOMETRY` column you should use [`ST_GeomFromGeoJson()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) in your `INSERT INTO`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (the_geom GEOMETRY);

INSERT INTO t (the_geom) VALUES (ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
        '{"type":"Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
          [
            [49.5703125,59.5343180010956],
            [54.84375,54.77534585936447],
            [63.28125,59.5343180010956],
            [54.84375,61.77312286453146],
            [49.5703125,60.930432202923335],
            [49.5703125,59.5343180010956]
          ]
        ]}'::json));

SELECT ST_AsText(the_geom,2) FROM t;

                                     st_astext                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POLYGON((49.57 59.53,54.84 54.78,63.28 59.53,54.84 61.77,49.57 60.93,49.57 59.53))
(1 Zeile)
```

[image]

Further reading:

- [`GeoJSON documentation`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-1.5)